# How do I specify a negative pattern in an svn:ignore value

Tags: svn, design-patterns, svnignore

I'm using SVN as my VCS.
I have a folder where I keep user-uploaded files. Obviously I don't need those under version control. However, there is a single file in the folder, which I need - .htaccess.

It's already under version control, but how do I specify that I need all other files besides .htaccess ignored in that folder?

I've come across this article: [ThoughtsPark.org: Using negative patterns for Subversion's svn:ignore property](http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/38), but the approach given is kind of cryptic to me and I'm not able to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If they files aren't in version control, what problems are they causing that they need to be ignored? (I do this fairly often myself without using ignore. Maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: If I have a really deep folder tree with lots of files, the unneeded files just get in the way using the SVN client. That's the minor obstacle. The major one is that I cannot be sure that some of the other devs won't commit their files by mistake. You see. most will pay attention not to, but it suffices for a single dev to fail in that.

Comment: I'm using SmartSVN and the command-line svn client. In both cases I have a bunch of unversioned files scattered around. In SmartSVN I'm seeing those in the COMMIT dialog and in the command-line client I see them when I issue 'svn status'

Answer (score 3):

Subversion will not apply the patterns in `svn:ignore` to already versioned files. So in your example the pattern `*` should be OK. Just ignore everything unversioned.

Comment: schot, thanks for your tip! This works for me for the situation at hand, but still does not answer my question

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you make a file pattern which matches all files, except .htaccess. In the article, they use character classes to make such a pattern.

E.g.

```
[^a]*
```

Matches any file which first letter is not an a. This won't work if you specify the full .htaccess filename like this, but the following may work for you:

```
[^.]*
```

This will ignore any file not starting with a dot.

Comment: They use slightly different syntax though... Should I use your syntax or theirs?

Comment: I don't understand what is different. They have a pattern on each line, which is good. They match extensions (i.e. the end of the filename) so they have `*foo`, where the asterisk matches anything. If you want to match a filename starting with a dot, you would have `.*`. A filename not starting with a dot would be `[^.]*`. That is, something else than a dot, followed by anything.

Comment: 'different syntax' I was referring to the negation character. The use *[!x], while you use [^a]*